# How to create installable (.exe) file from PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt

I have created a GUI in Designer and used 'loadui' to add functionality. So basically, I have a .ui file for design and a .py file which contains the functions. Code in brief is below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QFileDialog,QMainWindow,QMessageBox
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import pymssql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
        loadUi("MCQ1.ui",self)
        self.BrowDB.clicked.connect(self.load_dbase)
        self.SelectDB.clicked.connect(self.select_dbase)
    
    def load_dbase(self):
        engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://(local)')
        query = "select name FROM sys.databases;"
        data = pd.read_sql(query,engine)

    def select_dbase(self):
        global db_value
        db_value = self.select_db.currentText()    
        self.ChosenDB.setText("Chosen DB: "+db_value)
        return db_value

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = MainWindow()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(MainWindow)
widget.setFixedSize(900, 800)
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How do I create an installable (.exe) file with this?

Comment: what is *installable file*? is executable file(.exe)?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes.. thats what i meant.. executable file

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [fman build system](https://build-system.fman.io/).

With this system, it is possible to create an executable file.

A few additional steps are required:

1. install fbs
2. create new fbs project via command line:

> fbs startproject

3. modify the freshly created src/main/python/main.py by implementing your code:

```
    from fbs_runtime.application_context.PyQt5 import ApplicationContext
    
    # start of your code
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QFileDialog,QMainWindow,QMessageBox
    from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
    import pymssql
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    
    class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
       # [...]
    # end of your code
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        appctxt = ApplicationContext()
        # minor modification to the template to start your window
        window = MainWindow()
        exit_code = appctxt.app.exec()
        sys.exit(exit_code)
```

5. test if everything is set up correctly via command line:

> fbs run

4. create exectutable via command line:

> fbs freeze

Now you should have a new folder "target", which contains an executable of your program.

If you run into any trouble, check out [the tutorial](https://github.com/mherrmann/fbs-tutorial) and the [manual of fbs](https://build-system.fman.io/manual/), which should cover most issues. Additionally, it further illustrates how to create an installer package from the executable file.